# Store not seeing changes on grid in extjs4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am trying to save the changes from the grid to the store but I am not really sure if I'm doing it the right way.

STORE:

```
store_jvhdr = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        model: 'model_jvhdr',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            api: {
                read: './journalservlet?batNbr='+batNbr+'&operation=GET_RECORD',
                update: './journalservlet',
                create: './journalservlet'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true,
        listeners: {
            load: function(store, records, successful){
                ...
            }
        }
        });
```

This are the listeners attached to the grid

```
listeners: {
   itemdblclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e){
    ...
   },
   edit: function(editor, e){
      console.log('test');
      store_jvdtl.commitChanges();
      store_jvdtl.sync();
   }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `store_jvdtl.sync();` is correct but I don't think you want to call `commitChanges()` the reason for this is that `commitChanges()` marks the records in the store as 'clean' or rather, removes their dirty state.

As a result, when you call `sync()` the store doesn't think it has any changes to send, so I'd have thought you wouldn't get the ajax requests made to your proxy api urls.

Comment: well I tried removing the commitChanges line and it still doesnt work. One more thing is I don't know how to package the whole store data to a one json data / request parameter to be transferred to my servlet.